# Looking for location intelligence tools and user experience reports

Tags: business

I am looking for location intelligence tools (= combination of business intelligence + GIS). I had a look at several options: SpagoBI, Microstrategy + VisualCrossing, Yellowfin, and Map Intelligence.
Can anyone tell me about their experience using these tools? Or maybe I missed some other options?

Answer (score 0):

The company that I work for uses Telerik to implement solutions where GIS and BI is combined together. You can have a look at [www.p1m1.com](http://www.p1m1.com) and [www.telerik.com](http://www.telerik.com).

Comment: Isn't telerik all about UI? I fail to see how this addresses the question (but I admit I don't use Telerik so I could be mistaken and you should elaborate a little).

Comment: Well It's not a Location Intelligence tool, however it's BI capabilities are very flexible and combined with map tools, they make a terrific solution. It's not custom tailored and ready for use, however It's easy to implement.

Comment: Perhaps you could elaborate on the telerik tools BI capabilities in your post with links to relevant citations. Otherwise this post looks like an ad for your company as it doesn't currently address the original question well. I am interested in any more details that would provide valuable insight for the community given any experience you have with BI & GIS tools.

Comment: Well, I thought It wasn't that hard to google Telerik. My comments are nothing but advertisement, as we are only serving B2B optimization & forecasting solutions. Not BI systems. However here you go: http://demos.telerik.com/silverlight/  http://www.kendoui.com/?utm_source=telerik&utm_medium=index-divs&utm_campaign=box